# ViewModel observed every back to fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I have MainActivity which is containing 5 Fragments (FragmentA, FragmentB, FragmentC....E) with ViewPager. FragmentA has viewModel and observing a MutableLiveData called "showPopupSuccess" which set to true after doing a task.

The problem is when i go to FragmentC and then get back to FragmentA. The popup is showing again because the observer looks like "reactivated". How to get rid of this? I want the mutableLiveData get resetted. So it has no value in it and not showing a popup

This is the video of the bug if you want to see further
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ay1IIQgOOtk

Comment: The correct way to fix this is to update the state of your UI when you go to another fragment. The fragment shows the popup again because the state is still the same. Add more states to represent that a "task was successful but already displayed" (or whatever), in this particular state your FragmentA still knows it's a success, but doesn't call the `showPopup()`. So when you click on (what I think) says "Profile" (the bottom bar), you should pass that onto your VM. The VM should push the state to make sure if you return, the popup is now shown again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your issue: Use the [`Event` wrapper](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)
Instead of "resetting" the `LiveData`, you can mark its content as `handled` when you observe it for the first time. Then your repeated observations know it has already been handled and can ignore it.

To create a better answer according to the guidelines I'm copying over the relevant information from the linked article:

**The wrapper:**

```kotlin
/**
 * Used as a wrapper for data that is exposed via a LiveData that represents an event.
 */
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

**In the ViewModel:**

```kotlin
// Instead of Boolean the type of Event could be popup
// parameters or whatever else.
private val _showSuccess = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()

val showSuccess : LiveData<Event<Boolean>>
    get() = _showSuccess
```

**In the Fragment:**

```kotlin
myViewModel.showSuccess.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
        // This is only executed if the event has never been handled
        showSuccess(...)
    }
})
```

Comment: When i go to fragment C and back to fragment A, is fragmentA recreated or just reshown after hidden?

Comment: That has nothing to do with your original question and cannot be answered here in a comment. If you have other questions about Fragments, please create a new Question. You asked about event deduplication in LiveData. I have no doubts this answer will do what you ask. When it does, please accept the answer so that it indicates a solved issue for other people.